# Mongoose & float values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, meanjs

My lat & lng numbers are being converted to strings.  My section integers are still the correct data type of Number.  How do I set up model so that I can get my lat & lng back out as Float rather than String?

I'm storing latLng data in my db.  Right now I have my data type set to Number for lat & lng.  When I check out my db I see this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("563bd98a105249f325bb8a7e"),
  "lat" : 41.8126189999999980,
  "lng" : -87.8187850000000054,
  "created" : ISODate("2015-11-05T22:34:50.511Z"),
  "__v" : 0,
  "section" : 0,
}
```

But when I get my data back out using express I get this:

```
{
  "_id": "563bd98a105249f325bb8a7e",
  "lat" : "41.8126189999999980",
  "lng" : "-87.8187850000000054",
  "__v": 0,
  "section" : 0,
  "created" : "2015-11-05T22:34:50.511Z",
}
```

My model:

```
var WaypointSchema = new Schema({
    lat: {
        type: Number
    },
    lng: {
        type: Number
    },
    section: {
        type: Number
    }
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now

    }
});

mongoose.model('Waypoint', WaypointSchema);
```

Express controller:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) { 
    Waypoint.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, waypoints) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(waypoints);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code that creates that output?

Comment: if you come to this question today, it is very important to check the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303993/4742336

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the mongoDB fully supports `float` type, the mongoose supports only type of `Number` which is integer. If you try to save to mongoDB float number using mongooses type of `Number` it will be converted to string.

To sort this out, you will need to load some plugin for mongoose which will extend its value types. There are some plugins which work best with currencies or dates, but in your case I would use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-double.

Your model after changes would look something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);

var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
var WaypointSchema = new Schema({
    lat: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    lng: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    section: {
        type: Number
    }
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

mongoose.model('Waypoint', WaypointSchema);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry but for my case, if I am trying to save a floating value then it is getting stored as Float only.

Comment: While this was true at the moment of answering, if you come to this question today, it is very important to check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303993/4742336

Answer (score 4):

As of the current version of mongoose (v5.12.6), It supports [Decimal128](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-Decimal128) which can be used for this.

Comment: this very important answer for those that come to this question today.

Answer (score -1):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Waypoint = new Schema({
    lat: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    lng: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    section: {
        type: Number
    }
 point: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2d'
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
event.index({
    Point: '2dsphere'
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Waypoint', Waypoint);

waypoint.save(point: [parseFloat(values.latitude), parseFloat(values.longitude)],)
```